# Searching for backslash in a string with Powershell

Tags: powershell, backslash

I need to search for the amount of backslashes in a string to determine some file path parameters. I have not worked out a way to seach for a backslash without Powershell thinking it is an escapee character.

```
([regex]::Matches($FilePath, "\" )).count
```

Or

```
$a -match "\"
```

These both come up with an error "Illegal \ at end of pattern"

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can escape a backslash with a backslash:

```
[Regex]::Matches($FilePath, "\\").Count
```