# How to use backslash character as a literal in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, replace

I am attempting to trim a string down using the `replace`command and the character `\` as the identifier.

See example below:

```
$string = "Hello\Hi"
$newstring = $string -replace ".*\"
$newstring
```

By my reasoning this should print `Hi` in the CMD window.

However instead I am receiving the following:

```
Invalid regular expression pattern: .*\.
At line:1 char:30
+ $newstring = $string -replace <<<<  ".*\"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (.*\:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegularExpression
```

I am assuming this is due to the `\` character being some kind of special symbol in powershell? As I am able to quite easily do the same thing substituting the `\` for a `/`.

Any advice?

Comment: ``\`` is not a special character for PowerShell, but is special character for regular expressions.

Comment: Are you able to advise if there is any way to use it in regular expressions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching for backslash in a string with Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35497077/searching-for-backslash-in-a-string-with-powershell) and [How to escape a backslash in PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36748923/how-to-escape-a-backslash-in-powershell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backslash is the escape character in regular expressions. It allows you to use a special character as a literal.

To use backslash as a literal you need to escape it with a backslash. For example:

`"Hello\Hi" -replace ".*\\"`

Answer (score 0):

> In some PowerShell expressions (matching operations) a backslash
>   character will be interpreted as the start of a Regular Expression,
>   (e.g. \w = match word) this is the industry-standard regex syntax.  To
>   escape this and treat the backslash as an ordinary character, double
>   it (replace \ with \\ )

Also:

> The PowerShell escape character is the grave-accent(`)

Many more helpful hints here:
http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html

To answer your get "hi" out of your string, you could do something like this:

```
($string.substring($string.indexof("\"),($string.length) - ($string.indexof("\")))) -replace "\\",""
```

I may be making it more complicated than it needs to be, but this works to get "hi" out of "hello\hi".

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

$string -replace [Regex]::Escape('Direct=TCP:123.123.123.123\private$\myqueue'), "Direct=TCP:231.231.231.231\private$\myqueue"